# Add custom "Install or run program from your media" to drive

Tags: windows, batch-file, autorun

Most DVD's/ISO's have an 'AutoRun' option (which is technically no AutoRun anymore) which allow the users to quickly do the intended task using the 'What-to-do-with-this'-dialogue of windows or using the right-click menu.
Because my HDD is messy and I need to open only one .bat inside all the time wherever I go (foreign computers) I would like to add this function to the drive to make the access quicker and also easier for other people.

So far i have added a custom label and icon to the autorun.inf inside the root of the drive and it works but even when i copy the autorun.inf from a working ISO file it won't show me the action on my drive (after re-plug ofc).

Does Windows just not allow these 'Hot-Actions' for HDD's?
Or is there another fix for this?
This is what i tried so far (my autorun.inf):

```
[autorun] 
label=Custom Name Yeah
icon=custom_logo_whoo.ico
open=Run.bat
shell\readme\command=Run.bat
shell\readme=Run my awesome software
shell=readme
```

Comment: Microsoft changes support for autorun at will and often disables it for security reasons. My suggestion: forget about it

Comment: I know it works for ISO's and i have also seen it with a brand new WD drive (one with pre-installed backup software) on some Win8 version.